# Upgrading IN-App subscription

Tags: android, upgrade, subscription

In my application, I allow the user to subscribe the App for 1 month and 6 months. I am stuck following scenario:
If user selects 1 month and then 6 months subscription on the same day. What will be the purchase expiry date? Will it be after 1 month or after 6 months or after 7(1+6) months?

Please guide me.

Comment: if user has paid twice then it should be added to current subscription making it 7 months

Comment: or is the balance will be credited to his account for future use? In developer.android, they have said something about upgrade/downgrade subscription, which talks about replacing the previous with current subscription.

Comment: well these are the policies you have to define, which completely  depends on you